# Correct mysql query to db

Tags: mysql, sql

I have db and such table in it

```
CREATE TABLE OrderDetails(
    OrderID int NOT NULL,
    ProductID int NOT NULL,
    UnitPrice double NOT NULL  DEFAULT '0',
    Quantity smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    Discount double NOT NULL  DEFAULT '0',
    foreign key (OrderID) references Orders (OrderID),
    foreign key (ProductID) references Products (ProductID)
    );
```

There is also other table called `Orders` and there are 1000 rows in it 
also in `projecttable` i have only 1000 rows

i have such a query

```
INSERT INTO OrderDetails(OrderID,ProductID,UnitPrice,Quantity,Discount)
    SELECT OrderID, ProductID, OrdDetUnitPrice, OrdDetQuantity, OrdDetDiscount
    FROM (SELECT OrdDetUnitPrice, OrdDetQuantity, OrdDetDiscount, ProdProductName, CustCompanyName, EmpFirstName, EmpLastName FROM test.projecttable) as pt INNER JOIN
            (SELECT ProductID, ProductName FROM Products) as p ON p.ProductName=pt.ProdProductName INNER JOIN
                (SELECT LastName, FirstName, EmpId FROM Employees ) as e ON pt.EmpLastName=e.LastName AND pt.EmpFirstName=e.FirstName INNER JOIN
                    (SELECT CustID, CompanyName FROM Customer) as c ON pt.CustCompanyName=c.CompanyName INNER JOIN
                            (SELECT OrderID, CustID, EmpID FROM Orders) as o ON c.CustID=o.CustID AND e.EmpID=o.EmpID;
```

Coudl someone tell me why it returns 4084 rows  if i only have 1000 in `Orders` table

Comment: How many rows your `SELECT OrderID ....` returns have you noticed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when you do an inner join, it returns one row for each time the value on one side matches the value on the other. Say for the first row in the order table, there is one customer, and one employee, but there are 4 products. So if I had to guess, I would say your system averages about 4.084 products per order.

I think it is the correct answer. Why do you think there should only be 1000 rows in the order details table?

Comment: Becouse i have only 1000 rows in Orders table so how shoudl i replace inner join?